# How can I find out the size, a rect has to be, to fit all rects inside a canvas, using a fixed amout of rects?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

**Context**

I'm creating a coloring pixels game clone using `canvas`
I save the state of a canvas inside an array that looks like this:

```
[{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":1,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":2,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":3,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":4,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":5,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":6,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":7,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":8,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":9,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":10,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":11,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":12,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":13,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":14,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":15,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":16,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":17,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":18,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":0,\"y\":19,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":0,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":1,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":2,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":3,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":4,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":5,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":6,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":7,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":8,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":9,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":10,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":11,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":12,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":13,\"pickedColor\":\"#8bc34a\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":14,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":15,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":16,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":17,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":18,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":1,\"y\":19,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":2,\"y\":0,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":2,\"y\":1,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":2,\"y\":2,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null},{\"x\":2,\"y\":3,\"pickedColor\":\"white\",\"colorCode\":null}]
```

So each rect has the `x` and `y` coordinates on it.
To draw the rect on the screen I use this function to calculate how big each "rect" has to be to fit inside the canvas bounds:

```
// width / height comes from props and rectSize comes from props
const [rectCountX, setRectCountX] = useState(Math.floor(width / rectSize));
const [rectCountY, setRectCountY] = useState(Math.floor(height / rectSize));
```

For example `width` and `height` might be `800` and `600` and the `rectSize` might be `30`.
That calculates how many `rects` I can draw in each direction.

Here is how I draw the initial board:

```
const generateDrawingBoard = (ctx) => {
    // Generate an Array of pixels that have all the things we need to redraw

    for (var i = 0; i < rectCountX; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < rectCountY; j++) {
        // this is the quint essence whats saved in a huge array. 1000's of these pixels.
        // With the help of this, we can redraw the whole canvas although canvas has not state or save functionality :)
        const pixel = {
          x: i,
          y: j,
          pickedColor: "white",
          // we don't know the color code yet, we generate that afterwards
          colorCode: null,
        };
        updateBoardData(pixel);
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.strokeRect(i * rectSize, j * rectSize, rectSize, rectSize);
      }
    }
  };
```

That works perfectly. The user draws the canvas and saves it into the database.

**The Problem**

I have a `pixelArtPreview` components. This gets the data from the database and for each pixelArt it will draw a rect but in a smaller size, so I can fit many rects on the page to present the user like a list of pixel Arts.

Therefore I need to recalculate the `rectSize` of each rect in the array to fit in the new `width` and `height`. Thats exactly where I'm banging my head at currently.

So here is the component I was mentioning:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { drawPixelArtFromState } from "../utils/drawPixelArtFromState";

const PixelArtPreview = ({ pixelArt }) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [ctx, setCtx] = useState(null);
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    // This is where I scale the original size
    // the whole pixelArt comes from the database and looks like this (example data):

    // { pixelArtTitle: "some title", pixelArtWidth: 1234, pixelArtHeight: 1234, pixels: [... (the array I shows above with pixels)]}
    canvas.width = pixelArt.pixelArtWidth * 0.5;
    canvas.height = pixelArt.pixelArtHeight * 0.5;
    setCanvas(canvas);
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    setCtx(context);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ctx) return;
    drawPixelArtFromState(pixelArt, ctx);
  }, [pixelArt, ctx]);
  return <canvas className="m-4 border-4" ref={canvasRef} />;
};

export default PixelArtPreview;
```

But the magic happens inside the imported function `drawPixelFromState(pixelArt, ctx)`

This is said function (with comments what my thaught process was):

```
export const drawPixelArtFromState = (pixelArt, ctx) => {
  // how much pixels have been saved from the original scale when the art has been created
  const canvasCount= JSON.parse(pixelArt.pixels).length;

  // how many pixels we have on X
  const xCount = JSON.parse(pixelArt.pixels)[canvasCount- 1].x;
  // how many pixels we have on Y
  const yCount = JSON.parse(pixelArt.pixels)[canvasCount- 1].y;

  // total pixles (canvas height * canvas.width with the scale of 0.5 so it matches the canvas from the component before)
  // this should give me all the pixels inside the canvas
  const canvasPixelsCount =
    pixelArt.pixelArtWidth * 0.5 * (pixelArt.pixelArtHeight * 0.5);

  // now i try to find out how big each pixel has to be
  const newRectSize = canvasPixelsCount / canvasCount;

  // this is for example 230 rects which can't be I see only 2 rects on the canvas with that much of a rectSize
  console.log(newRectSize);

  // TODO: Parse it instantly where we fetch it
  JSON.parse(pixelArt.pixels).forEach((pixel) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeRect(
      pixel.x * newRectSize,
      pixel.y * newRectSize,
      newRectSize,
      newRectSize
    );

    ctx.fillStyle = pixel.pickedColor;
    ctx.fillRect(
      pixel.x * newRectSize,
      pixel.y * newRectSize,
      newRectSize,
      newRectSize
    );
  });
};
```

Here is how that example looks like on screen (these are 4 separate canvas and can be seen on the grey border - I expect to see the whole pixel art inside the little canvas):

[image]

**The Question:**

I need to figure out the correct formula to calculate the new `rectSize` so all rects in the array can fit inside the new canvas `width` and `height`.
Is this even possible or do I need the old `rectSize` for the calculation to work?

### So **TL;DR**:  how big has every rect x to be, to fit all x rects in y canvas.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys after struggling for hours it finally clicked.
The calculation I made:

```
// now i try to find out how big each pixel has to be
  const newRectSize = canvasPixelsCount / rectCount;
```

Gives me the area of the pixel. But I just need one side of it (since `canvas.fillRect` only cares for the x value and thakes care of the area). So I need the square root of it.

```
// now i try to find out how big each pixel has to be
  const newRectSize = Math.sqrt(canvasPixelsCount / rectCount);
```

This now works perfectly.

Screenshot:

[image]